# CouchBase class not found in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, couchbase, nosql

I use couchbase nosql database by `ytake/laravel-couchbase` package in my laravel 5.1 project 
After install that package and run `php artisan serve` i got error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CouchbaseN1qlQuery' not found in /var/www/html/eee/vendor/ytake/laravel-couchbase/src/CouchbaseServiceProvider.php on line 71


 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
 Class 'CouchbaseN1qlQuery' not found
```

Comment: see the folder permissions.

Comment: which folder? vendor?

Comment: where the class it want here (CouchbaseServiceProvider.php on line 71) is present

Comment: in (CouchbaseServiceProvider.php on line 71) code is :                            `$this->app['db']->extend('couchbase', function ($config) {
            return new CouchbaseConnection($config);
        });`

Comment: other thing is , i install couchbase on ubuntu and in terminal i can run couchbase and i got result , but in `phpinfo()`  couchbase info not exist

Comment: You need the `ext-couchbase` extension installed

Comment: i installed from `https://github.com/couchbase/php-ext-couchbase`

Comment: but when i run `php -m` to see what ext installed , i got error `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/couchbase.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/couchbase.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: i got `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/couchbase.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/couchbase.so: undefined symbol: _zend_hash_str_update in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error for a long time.
For me, the problem was that the CLI user couldn't write in the laravel.log when the couchbase client was trying to write a warning to it. Check user permissions.